# How to prevent \endlinechar=-1 from interfering a loaded EPS image?

Tags: catcodes

I have to work in a block that begins with `\endlinechar=-1\relax` removing any space at the end of each line. After the `\endlinechar=-1\relax`, there will be codes related to loading an image (EPS,PNG,JPG,PDF) and drawing geometric objects (by PSTricks).

Unfortunately `\endlinechar=-1\relax` disrupts the structure of the loaded EPS image as follows.

[image]

```
% Trash.tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\endlinechar=-1\relax
% other settings go here
% ...
\includegraphics{Image.eps}% extension is explicitly specified to emphasize that it is an EPS image!
% other codes go here
% ...
\end{document}
```

How to prevent `\endlinechar=-1\relax` from interfering the loaded EPS image?

Note: this issue only occurs when loading EPS. Loading PDF or JPG has  been tested and there is no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message shows the error occurs in the `\Gread@eps` macro (which is part of the DVI/PS output driver and is of course EPS specific, which explains why PDF or JPG files are not affected). The code there wants to change the catcode of the end-of-line characters to 5 (RETURN, i.e. the normal value) but doesn't change the `\endlinechar` itself. Here it is -1 which isn't a valid input for `\catcode<char number>=<catcode>`. IMHO this is actually a bug in that code.

You need to either change the `\endlinechar` back to its normal value (13) around the `\includegraphics`, patch some internal macros of `graphics/x` to do that automatically or don't change the value of `\endlinechar` at all. In the latter case you could use `\catcode\endlinechar=9\relax` to make TeX ignore endline characters, instead of not inserting them as before with `\endlinechar=-1\relax`. It should lead to the same result in the document but will work with the `\Gread@eps` macro.

Comment: Question 1: Is it OK if I use `\catcode\endlinechar=9\relax` instead of `\endlinechar=-1\relax` for all cases (whether or not I import PDF,EPS,JPG,PNG images followed by PSTricks, equation, etc)? Question 2: Why is there `\catcode` in `\catcode\endlinechar=9\relax` while no `\catcode` in the previous `\endlinechar=-1\relax`? Is `\catcode` mandatory?

Comment: A1: Yes, it should be OK. A2: `\endlinechar` is an integer register which holds the ASCII number of the character which should be used for end-of-line characters (independent of their real ASCII code in the file). When you say `\endlinechar=-1\relax` then you assign -1 to `\endlinechar`. You can use this also in any place where you can use a number. So `\catcode\endlinechar=9\relax` says: Change the catcode of the character with the number currently stored in `\endlinechar` to 9 (ignore). You don't change the `\endlinechar` itself just its catcode.